# tbody animates opacity but not height

Tags: jquery, html

I want to have a table that the user can expand/contract the contents (but not the header) of the table with a nice-looking animation.

HTML:

```
<table class="generic-table" border="0" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
<tr class="generic-titlebar">
<th class="t2" colspan="3">
Announcements
<button class="chevron button" rel="forum_13"><img id="forum_13-showhide" class="showhide" src="/img/section_expanded.png" alt="show/hide"></button>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="forum_13">
<!-- Table Content here -->
</tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.chevron').click(function() {
    if($('#'+$(this).attr('rel')).is(':visible') ) {
        $('#'+$(this).attr('rel')+'-showhide').attr('src', '/img/section_collapsed.png');
        $.cookie($(this).attr('rel'), '-', {expires: 30, path: '/'});
    } else {
        $('#'+$(this).attr('rel')+'-showhide').attr('src', '/img/section_expanded.png');
        $.cookie($(this).attr('rel'), '+', {expires: 30, path: '/'});
    }
    $('#'+$(this).attr('rel')).animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' });
});
```

This code works for <div>s. But for the tbody, the height does not animate. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you animate the height of `<table>` rather than `<tbody>`?

**EDIT**
Is this what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/ebiewener/YawnP ?

You simply wrap the table in a div with overflow:hidden, and expand & contract that div as necessary.

Comment: That won't work because then the table would be completely hidden, and the user wouldn't be able to bring it back.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but I can make it work. Thanks.

Comment: Then please explain more clearly in the future what you're looking for. All you said was "I want to have a table that the user can expand/contract the contents (but not the header) of the table with a nice-looking animation."

Answer (score 0):

animating the height of the `td` will be the best option.